# Batch process images to 640px width but don't resize if less than 640px

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing

I have a huge amount of images that I would like to batch process with Photoshop (any version).

They're all different shapes and sizes in terms of resolution and quality.

I want to batch process them all to 70% quality and a max of 640px wide. The quality part is easy, it's the width that's causing me a problem.

Some of the images are less than 640px wide so I don't want to resize these, just change their quality. Is there a way to not make those images 640px, just anything that is bigger than 640px?

I'm talking thousands of images so it's not a manual job!!

Comment: Probably best to use a script. This might help. http://forums.adobe.com/thread/693986

Comment: Do you have to use Photoshop? [IrfanView](http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/irfanview_portable) also has a basic batch resize feature.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this, but it'll require a little bit of work outside of Photoshop.

You'll want to split all the images into two different folders. One will contain all images with a width greater than 640 and the other will contain those with less.

An easy way to do this (on Windows) is to open up Windows Explorer and navigate to your folder.

Then in the top-right search: `dimensions:>640` -- this will return all images with a width greater than 640px. Move these to a separate folder.

This part should also be possible on a Mac but I'm not entirely sure of the process. I would consult Google on that one.

Now run a batch process to set the quality and resize the images bigger than 640px, and then another process on those smaller than or equal to 640px just to set the quality.

Unfortunately other than this you'll need to use custom scripting to handle it within photoshop.